# « Être dans le train en marche » : est-ce toujours usuel ?

Tags: prépositions, locutions, lexique, transports

Dans un [article](https://www.lapresse.ca/environnement/politique-verte/201901/07/01-5210236-le-canada-rate-sa-cible-sur-la-vente-de-voitures-electriques.php) on peut lire que 97% des véhicules électriques vendus au Canada l'ont été au Québec, en Ontario et en Colombie-Britannique, confirmant à mon avis lesquels des Canadiens ont à cœur l'environnement et lesquels se [comportent](https://www.lapresse.ca/affaires/economie/automobile/201901/03/01-5209872-le-desinteret-pour-les-petites-voitures-pese-sur-les-ventes-de-vehicules-aux-e-u.php) essentiellement comme nos voisins du sud, où l'état fédéral mène un combat d'arrière-garde [mensonger](https://www.lapresse.ca/affaires/economie/energie-et-ressources/201810/24/01-5201545-exxonmobil-poursuivi-pour-tromperie-liee-au-changement-climatique.php) ([2](https://www.lapresse.ca/environnement/climat/201801/10/01-5149570-new-york-intente-une-poursuite-contre-cinq-geants-petroliers.php)) contre le consensus scientifique sur le climat. Quoiqu'il en soit la Canada a raté sa [cible](http://www.publications.gc.ca/site/eng/9.636849/publication.html) et on peut lire que :

> Le rapport signalait que le train des véhicules électriques était déjà
>   en marche et que le Canada n'était pas à [bord](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bord).
>
> [ *Le Canada rate sa cible sur la vente de voitures électriques*, La
>   presse, 7 janvier 2019 ]

Sur [Larousse en ligne](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/train/78943/locution?q=train%20en%20marche#16001459) et [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/prendre_le_train_en_marche) je n'ai trouvé que la locution *prendre le train en marche* signifiant « se joindre à une entreprise, à une action lancée par d'autres et déjà en cours » (Larousse en ligne). Seul le TLFi traite de la locution *être [dans](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dans) le [train](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/train) en marche* signifiant « participer à une action ». Un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*%20dans%20le%20train%20en&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20dans%20le%20train%20en%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmonter%20dans%20le%20train%20en%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsauter%20dans%20le%20train%20en%3B%2Cc0) n'a été d'aucun secours.

---

- *Être dans le train en marche* est-il encore employé et peut-on brièvement illustrer ?
- La substitution de la préposition *dans* par la locution *à bord de*
  (être à bord du train en marche) est-elle usitée ; dans l'extrait
  pouvait-on remanier la phrase afin de conserver la préposition *dans*
  ; conçoit-on une manière plus claire de s'exprimer et si oui comment
  ?

  - Dans le contexte de l'article, pourquoi était-il plus juste ou non de
    dire que le Canada n'avait *pas su prendre le train en marche* :
    suffit-il de répondre à la question *qui a lancé ce « train »* pour
    le déterminer ?

Comment: C'est une métaphore, qui n'est pas nouvelle mais qui n'est pas assez systématique pour avoir le statut d'expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prendre le train en marche = prendre part à une action qui a déjà commencé

« Être dans le train en marche » n'est pas une expression en France (je ne sais pas pour la Canada, je suis français).

La partie « le train des véhicules électriques était déjà en marche » est tout à fait compréhensible. Ce n'est pas une expression, mais c'est une tournure qui passe bien. C'est un jeu avec l'expression que tout le monde connaît, donc nécessite une toute petite réflexion pour comprendre de quoi il s'agit.
Si c'est pour un texte qui doit pouvoir être lu très facilement, par exemple qui défile en bas d'un écran, alors la phrase n'est pas bonne.

dans / à bord : les deux sont parfaitement corrects. « à bord » est légèrement plus soutenu.
Je ne vois pas de solution pour conserver « dans ». La phrase devient lourde et torturée : « Le rapport signalait que le Canada n'était pas dans le train des véhicules électriques qui était déjà en marche ». C'est vraiment laid et difficilement compréhensible.

Il est plus efficace (et non « juste ») de dire que le Canada n'a pas pris le train en marche, parce que c'est une expression que tout le monde comprend. La tournure de l'article peut être perçue comme un léger trait d'humour ou de mise en avant des capacités littéraires de l'auteur, mais vraiment légèrement.

Savoir qui a lancé le train n'a strictement aucune importance, dans aucun cas.

Mon avis personnel : Le rapport [indiquait / signalait] [que concernant les / qu'à propos des] véhicules électriques, le Canada n'avait pas su prendre le train en marche.

Comment: Merci ! Notez cependant au TLFi, [Michel Debatisse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Debatisse) (Français) : « [Les femmes] sont, comme les hommes, dans le train en marche. Au stade du syndicalisme, il importe qu'elles restent dans le train. »

Comment: Il faudrait sans doute un spécialiste pour nous éclairer sur les choix des rédacteurs du TLF (dernière version 1994 !) pour identifier ce qui constitue une locution digne d'y figurer.

Answer (score 2):

> Être dans le train en marche est-il encore employé et peut-on
>   brièvement illustrer ?

En tout cas pas en tant qu'expression consacrée, et les éléments cités en sont de bons signes. Mais cela reste une métaphore tout à fait valide.

> La substitution de la préposition dans par la locution à bord de (être
>   à bord du train en marche) est-elle usitée ; dans l'extrait pouvait-on
>   remanier la phrase afin de conserver la préposition dans ; conçoit-on
>   une manière plus claire de s'exprimer et si oui comment ?

Je regarderais plutôt la phrase sous l'angle de la métaphore *"le train de ... est en marche"*, à laquelle on a accolé une chute sarcastique : *"... et le Canada n'est pas à bord"*. Remanier la phrase totalement annulerait à mon avis l'effet de contraste, de juxtaposition.

Toutefois, *"... et le Canada n'était pas **dedans**"* marcherait aussi bien, s'il s'agit juste de remplacer ce mot.

> Dans le contexte de l'article, pourquoi était-il plus juste ou non de
>   dire que le Canada n'avait pas su prendre le train en marche

Le reformuler ainsi serait sémantiquement proche mais :

- La notion de "déjà" serait plus difficilement véhiculable (*"ne pas savoir prendre un train déjà en marche"* ? ...)
- Encore une fois, on perdrait le léger effet ironique

Comment: Merci ! Je veux simplement être certain de bien comprendre votre première affirmation (... _et les éléments cités en sont de bons signes_.) Vous parlez de mes références à _Wiktionnaire_ et _Larousse en ligne_ où c'est formellement absent ? Brièvement que pensez-vous de mon commentaire sous l'autre réponse ?

Comment: Oui, je parle des références et de la recherche Ngram.